# Feature Folder Structure in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to create feature folder structure in ASP.NET Core 6 web project similar to one described in following article:
https://scottsauber.com/2016/04/25/feature-folder-structure-in-asp-net-core/  ?

[image]

Project structure:

- WebPublic
- WebCommon

following code was working in Asp.net Core 2.1 in "WebCommon" project which is added as reference in "WebPublic" project.

[image]

IViewLocationExpander Interface can be used if Nuget package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" is referenced in project, but latest version (updated 12/4/2018) is only 2.2.0.

Following error occurs even if in "WebCommon" project "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" is referenced:

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler' Version=6.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for .NET6. You can skip the approach with ViewLocationExapnder and just exapnd on how the views are located by configuring the `RazorViewEngineOptions` as (for example, in your Program.cs where services is `WebApplicationBuilder` builder.Services):

```cs
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add($"/Features/Codebooks/{{1}}/{{0}}{RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension}");
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add($"/Views/Shared/{{0}}{RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension}");
});
```

Here I configured it to look into Features/Codebooks/{controllerName}/{actionName}.cshtml, and that works very well.

[image: visual studio screenshot of C# code and solution explorer showing Features folder]

Comment: Implementing this is giving me errors for view models: `CS0256 The type or namespace name 'SomeViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`. I put the view models in the feature folder they belong to.